# Why does ICollection(T) not implement ICollection?

Tags: .net, generics, collections

I just came across a scenario with a unit test where I am using `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()` with two instances of `ICollection(T)`. However, CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent takes two ICollection objects as parameters and `ICollection(T)` does not implement `ICollection`. Why is that? I would think that since `ICollection(T)` is the generic equivalent to `ICollection`, it should implement `ICollection` for interoperability with older code; otherwise, if `ICollection(T)` is doing something fundamentally different than `ICollection`, it should not even be called `ICollection(T)`.

Comment: @BartSipes Last but not least, it takes extra work for a generic collection *implementation* to implement a non-generic interface - you have to duplicate methods and have casts and generally make a non-typesafe mess of things. **Forcing** everyone who wants to implement their own custom collections to do that would be annoying, the .NET base library mostly does that for convenience in migrating old code. (This doesn't really apply to `ICollection` vs `ICollection<T>`, but it does to `IList` and `IList<T>`.)