# Why generic ICollection<T> does not inherit some non-generic interface with Count property?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

In .NET generic interface `ICollection<T>` has `Count` property itself. But it does not inherit any non-generic interface with a `Count` property.

So, now if you want determine count of non-generic `IEnumerable`, you have to check whether it is implementing `ICollection` and if not, you have to use reflection to lookup whether it does implement generic `ICollection<X>`, since you do not know the generic argument `X`.

If [`ICollection<T>` cannot inherit from directly from `ICollection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353346/why-doesnt-icollectiont-implement-icollection), why there is not another non-generic interface with `Count` property only?

Is it just bad design choice?

**UPDATE**: To make the question more clear, I demonstrate the issue on my current implementation:

```
    static int? FastCountOrZero(this IEnumerable items)
    {
        if (items == null)
            return 0;
        var collection = items as ICollection;
        if (collection != null)
            return collection.Count;
        var source = items as IQueryable;
        if (source != null)
            return QueryableEx.Count(source);
        // TODO process generic ICollection<> - I think it is not possible without using reflection
        return items.Cast<object>().Count();
    }
```

Comment: IEnumerable might be infinite, so Count doesn't apply.

Comment: But not class that implements both `IEnumerable` and `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Ultimately, there just isn't an `ICountedEnumerable` interface. It would be nice if there were, but there isn't.

Comment: Also note that if you know something is an `IEnumerable<Foo>`, if it implements `ICollection<T>` at all it will *probably* implement `ICollection<Foo>` - modulo covariance, of course.

Comment: Why don't you use `coll.Count()` and let .NET determine if it has a `Count` property or not?

Comment: Yes, but that's how `Enumerable.Count()` is implemented.

Comment: `Count()` is just for generic version of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @TN.: then you could still use `enumerable.Cast<object>().Count()` since it still implements `ICollection`  and therefore `Enumerable.Count` will use the `Count` property instead of enumerating all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes I can, but `Enumerable.Count()` could not use the count optimalization.

Comment: @TN.: it can if the object implements `ICollection`. For example: `IEnumerable enumerable = new List<string>(); enumerable = enumerable.Cast<object>(); int count = enumerable.Cast<object>().Count()`. This will still use the `Count` property under the hood.

Comment: @TN.: `Enumerable.Cast` will not return a `CastIterator` if the argument already implements `IEnumerable<TResult>`. Then it just returns the original object.

Comment: @TimSchmelter But this I can solve directly by casting to `ICollection`. It does not help with `ICollection<T>`. Which is my question. (Since `ICollection<T>` does not inherit non-generic `ICollection`.)

Comment: Both ICollection and ICollection<T> have a Count getter that must be implemented, so I don;t understand your question.  In addition, I agree with Wilbert regarding IEnumerable and Count not making sense on that interface.

Comment: @PaulMarques Check the implementation of `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count()` in `System.Core.dll`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it just bad design choice?

Probably the answer is *yes*.

And to solve this issue in .NET 4.5 MS introduced [`IReadOnlyCollection<out T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542) interface, which is covariant for reference types.

So you can rewrite your code like following

```
static int? FastCountOrZero(this IEnumerable items)
{
    if (items == null)
        return 0;
    var collection = items as ICollection;
    if (collection != null)
        return collection.Count;
    var roCollection = items as IReadOnlyCollection<object>; // only for reference types
    if (roCollection != null)
        return roCollection.Count;
    var source = items as IQueryable;
    if (source != null)
        return QueryableEx.Count(source);

    return items.Cast<object>().Count();
}
```

And as last resort you can cast `items` to dynamic object and invoke `Count` property dynamicly.

```
if (items.GetType().GetInterface("System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1") != null)
{
    dynamic dynamic = items;
    return dynamic.Count;
}
```

Comment: For me +1, thank you for the hint with `IReadOnlyCollection<>`.

Answer (score -1):

Best I can propose is this. Note (As mentioned in comments, Ienumerable can be infinite)

```
public static int CountIEnumerable (IEnumerable t)
{
    var iterator = t.GetEnumerator();
    var max = int.MaxValue;
    int count = 0;
    while (iterator.MoveNext() && (count < max))
    {
        count++;
    }

    //OPTIONAL
    //if (count >= max)
    //{
       //   throw new Exception("Collection is too big");
    //}
    return count;
    }
```

Edit : You can replace "int" by Int64 :)

Comment: This is the naive implementation. But it could be too slow if there are lot of items and if the `t` also implements `ICollection<X>`. Btw. you also should check whether the `iterator` does not implement `IDisposable`, if so, you have to dispose the iterator in order to release resources.