# Why does HashSet<T> not implement ICollection?

Tags: .net, collections, interface, hashset

I am going to write a library to traverse an object graph (like some kind of serialization).
You will need to judge if an object is a collection in the traverse, so the `ICollection` came out of my mind. (`string` has also implemented `IEnumerable`)

But it is really weird that almost all containers in Collections have implemented `ICollection` except `HashSet` only implemented `ICollection<T>`...

I have checked out almost all common containers in `System.Collections` namespace:

```
ArrayList : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable  
BitArray : ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable  
Hashtable : IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback, ICloneable  
Queue : ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable  
SortedList : IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable  
Stack : ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable  
Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDictionary, ICollection, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback
HashSet<T> : ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback, ISet<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable  
LinkedList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback  
List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable  
Queue<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable  
SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable  
SortedList<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable  
SortedSet<T> : ISet<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback  
Stack<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

Is this a bug? Or there are some reason behind?

Comment: I believe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353346/why-doesnt-icollectiont-implement-icollection) is relevant to your question.

Comment: The .NET collection hierarchy is really messed up.

Comment: If you are upgrading 1.1 code to 2.0 the fact that `List<T>` implements `ICollection` arguably helps you replace old uses of `ArrayList` (arguably it would be nicer to just have compiler errors pointing to where you need to upgrade to `ICollection<T>`). There isn't a non-generic version of `HashSet<T>` prior to it being introduced with 3.5, so one reason for supporting `ICollection` with the most of the others isn't there.

Comment: @JonHanna But `SortedSet<>` is an even newer type, and it does implement non-generic `ICollection`?

Comment: Corresponding meta post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293815/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yep, but you could argue that it shouldn't. For that matter you could argue that `List<T>` shouldn't either, but you'd have a stronger case with `HashSet<T>` and `SortedSet<T>`. It's design decisions so it's more about what you can argue as a clue to what someone did argue than immutable laws of nature.

Answer (score 0):

`ICollection` isn't anywhere near as useful now as it was with .NET 1.1 when there was no `ICollection<T>` offering greater type safety. There's very little one can usefully do with `ICollection` that one can't do with `ICollection<T>`, often with greater efficiency and/or type safety, especially if one writes generic methods for those cases where one might want to do something with collections of different element types.

This though begs the question of why the likes of `List<T>` *did* implement `ICollection`. But when `List<T>` was introduced with .NET 2.0 all legacy code was using `ICollection` and `ArrayList`, not `ICollection<T>` and `List<T>`. Upgrading code to use `List<T>` rather than `ArrayList` can be a pain, especially if it means having to either immediately change all uses of `ICollection` it would hit to use `ICollection<T>` or, even worse, double up because a method was being hit with the `List<T>` that was also being hit with other non-generic collections and so versions of the method would be needed for each. Implementing `ICollection` eased the upgrade path by allowing people to be more piecemeal in how they took advantage of generic collections.

When `HashSet<T>` came out generics had been in use for three years already, and there was not a previous non-generic hash-set type provided by the framework, so there was less of an upgrade pain, and hence less of a motivation for supporting `ICollection`.

Comment: ICollection is very useful for determining that object is finite non-lazy collection.

Most people just use IEnumerable to determine that object is some kind of collection but IEnumerable can be lazy and/or infinite.

So ICollection is smallest interface that almost all finite non-lazy collections support. And it is very annoying that few collections like HashSet<T>, ImmutableQueue<T>, ImmutableStack<T> does not.